# Sql fetch data with join

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, left-join

Here there two table **Transaction** and **Refundtransaction**

I want to fetch the data using join and duplicate data should be fetch.

I am using this query

```
select tr.transactionid, tr.customerid, tr.custname,
       rt.Amount, rt.Refund_Amount, rt.transactionid,   rt.referenceid
from Transaction tr 
left join RefundTransaction rt on rt.referenceid = tr.transactionid
```

It is not giving proper data.  It is not selecting duplicate data from refund data

[image: Data and expected result]

please help
here i am inserting image from which you can get actual scenario.

Comment: I think for the provided data ,your query will work fine. It will pick the duplicate refund transactions for the matching transactionID. Only change is in the select query tour first column should replace with rt.transactionid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the image, you need to place the `TRANSACTION` table in the `LEFT JOIN`. Then only you can get all the entries from `RefundTransaction` table.

```
SELECT rt.transactionid
    ,tr.customerid
    ,tr.custname
    ,tr.Amount AS Refund_Amount
    ,rt.transactionid
    ,rt.referenceid
    ,rt.Amount 
FROM RefundTransaction rt
LEFT JOIN [TRANSACTION] tr ON rt.referenceid = tr.transactionid
```

Answer (score 1):

This Could be simply solvedd using inner join between the two as per your image

```
SELECT t.transactionid, t.customerid, t.custname,
       rt.Amount, rt.Refund_Amount, rt.transactionid,   rt.referenceid
FROM TRANSACTION t
innerjoin [RefundTransaction ] rt ON rt.referenceid = t.transactionid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all datas you have to make a full outer join

```
select tr.transactionid,  tr.customerid,  tr.custname,    rt.Amount, rt.Refund_Amount,   rt.transactionid,   rt.referenceid from Transaction tr full outer join RefundTransaction rt on rt.referenceid = tr.transactionid
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins) you can find more info for joins

Answer (score 0):

You are doing excatly opposite for joins.

This should work.

```
select tr.transactionid, tr.customerid, tr.custname,
       rt.Amount, rt.Refund_Amount, rt.transactionid,   rt.referenceid
from RefundTransaction tr left join
     Transaction rt
     on rt.referenceid = tr.transactionid
```